# LibGDX - Best way to adjust fire rate in a loop

Tags: java, libgdx, timing, rate

I'm making a 2D platformer / shooter with LibGDX. I'm having this loop where holding fire-button down causes bullets to fly from the main character's gun the whole duration while the fire-button is pressed down (rapid fire). That part works perfectly and as intended. **However, I'd like the rate of fire to be a bit slower.**  Currently the loop just adds a bullet to the world on each game frame which means the rate of fire is ridiculously high.

I've been trying to find a good way to do this, to no avail. Any suggestions would be vastly appreciated.

the loop:

```
if (keys.get(Keys.FIRE)) {
    player.setState(State.FIRING);
        world.addBullet(new Bullet(1f,1f,0));
}
```

Comment: Use the `delta` time you get for each run  of the loop, and fire the bullet only when a certain time elapsed.

Comment: Do not use the `new `statement inside of the gameloop! Use a pooled Version of the Bullet.

Comment: because you create a new object whenever hes fireing instead of using the same object if it's unused

Comment: @BennX but how can i create the `Bullet` without creating one. I know libgdx has the `Pools`, but they only work with no-parameter constructors.

Comment: override the newObject Method or simply write your own pool. Use a simple List and add an attribute is useable. If you start a bullet you take the next useable of the pool. if there is no useable add a new one to the pool. Don't forget to make them useabile after they collided. Take a look at Pool pattern http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ObjectPool.aspx . Or simple extend the Pool from libgdx and extend it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a delay mechanism by having a variable which counts down the time and every time it hits 0, you make one shot and reset the time, for example to 0.2f when you want the player to shoot every 0.2s:

```
private float fireDelay;

public void render(float deltaTime) {
    fireDelay -= deltaTime;
    if (keys.get(Keys.FIRE)) {
        player.setState(State.FIRING);
        if (fireDelay <= 0) {
            world.addBullet(new Bullet(1f,1f,0));
            fireDelay += 0.2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `fireDelay = 0.2;` is not correct, use `fireDelay += 0.2;` instead. This has greater accuracy, you won't lose milliseconds.

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you! Will be very useful for other purposes as well. The best kind of advice, sir.

Comment: fireDelay -= deltaTime; should be inside the (keys.get(Keys.FIRE))  to work proper.

Answer (score 2):

Use a constant to hold the fire rate and add a timing mechanism, like so:

```
public static final long FIRE_RATE = 200000000L;
public long lastShot;

if(System.nanoTime() - lastShot >= FIRE_RATE) {
    world.addBullet(new Bullet(1f,1f,0));
    lastShot = System.nanoTime();
}
```

Comment: Using nanoTime here is not really intuitive, plus it would be more slow. Especially when it's in the main loop and on mobile devices.

Comment: What does being intuitive have to do with this? Using System.nanoTime() has very little performance impact.

Comment: So everyone can instantly understand what 200000000L is? I don't think so. And it is for sure less efficient than using the deltaTime which is provided anyway.

Comment: Yes, everyone should be able to recognise that 200000000L is a 64-bit integer value equal to 200 million. Nanotime simply returns the current system clock time as a 64-bit integer. If you're really so concerned over a few nanoseconds performance difference, then that's your problem.

Comment: I'm perfectly aware what 200000000L is, technically. But if I see it in code, I do not know what the *meaning* of it is. Is it 2 seconds? 0.2 seconds? 20 seconds? 0.02seconds? I have to count the zeroes, probably miscount them twice and then need to think how many nanoseconds there are in a second... how is this intuitive?

Comment: I think milli time should be accurate enaught. I am using almost the same approach in my game. If you allready have the delta time in your method (for example in the act() method) then it would be easier and also nicer to use in my oppinion. But as i said i am using `TimeUtils.millis()` cause i otherwise i would need to give delta to 3 methods in a chain or call `Gdx.graphics.getDelta()`. Both work well.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen @noone s answer and it is correct. I just answer you, because i had to add the same to my game. What i did: I had a variable `boolean attacking`, which stores if you are holding firebutton. Then i had 2 more variables: `float bps`, which stores how many bullets you can shoot per second and `float reloadTime`, which stores how long it takes to reload an empty magazin, if you use one. I also store a `long time` and a `boolean reloading`. Time stores the `TimeUtils.millis()` of your last shot, the reloading stores if you are reloading the magazin or just shooting. Then in the attack method i call a method: `public boolean readyToAttack()`, in which i compare `TimeUtils.millis()` to my variable `time`. If `reloading = true`, `TimeUtils.millis() - reloadTime` has to bigger then `time`. If not, `TimeUtils.millis() - (1000 / bps)` has to be bigger then `time`. If this is the case the method returns true and i can shoot. Noones solution is simpler, but for me bps is easier to understand so i used this.
Hope it helps